# Discord.py Команда с таймером

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Хотелось бы попросить помощи.

Хочу сделать бота, который будет после команды создавать сообщение и создавать реакцию под своим сообщением, а после определенного промежутка времени (которое я укажу в команде) он будет выбирать рандомно тех людей, которые прожали реакцию бота и пингом, выбирать их.

Облазил много вариантов, но так и не нашел ни инфы, ни примера команды. Либо я глупый, либо не умею искать. Буду благодарен даже за информацию по моему вопросу!

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не ищите готовый код, а постарайтесь придумать реализацию самостоятельно.
Искать в этом деле нужно только отдельные, непонятные вам этапы создания команды.

На самом деле здесь главное начать)

**Cразу извините за длинный ответ, просто хочется, чтобы вы разобрались, а не просто скопировали код)*

---

Создайте команду, которая принимает необходимые для полной работы параметры и создает сообщение - на вряд ли здесь возникнут трудности:

```py
@bot.command()
async def random_pick(ctx, wait_seconds: int):
    msg = await ctx.send('Нажмите  внизу, чтобы участвовать')
```

Команда принимает время для ожидания и создает сообщение, **но реакции под ним пока нет.**

Что делать, если не знаете как работать с реакциями? Гуглить или читать документацию, где все подробно расписано. Советую почитать краткое [**руководство**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Вбиваем в поиск ключевое слово `reaction` и в списке видим что-то похожее на то, что мы ищем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит, теперь известно, как поставить реакцию под сообщением - добавляем это и подключим в функцию ожидание в течение `wait_seconds`:

```py
@bot.command()
async def random_pick(ctx, wait_seconds: int):
    msg = await ctx.send('Нажмите  внизу, чтобы участвовать')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await asyncio.sleep(wait_seconds)
```

Теперь нужно узнать список пользователей, которые поставили реакцию.

На изображении выше видим, что класс `discord.Message` имеет свойство `reactions`. Если открыть страницу, то можно узнать, что свойство хранит в себе список объектов типа [`discord.Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.Reaction):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у объекта [`discord.Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.Reaction) есть метод `users()` - переходим к нему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, что достаточно забавно, здесь даже есть пример выбора случайного пользователя, прям в документации)

Можете [**посмотреть**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.Reaction.users) самостоятельно

---

Также здесь надо отметить, что сообщение `msg` на данный момент не имеет  реакций, так как в переменной хранится его состояние на момент отправки, а реакцию мы добавили позже. Поэтому нужно получить объект сообщения заново:

```
msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
```

И вот теперь уже можно получить список пользователей. Нашу реакцию поставил бот, поэтому она в списке первая, то есть индекс - `0`:

```
users = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
```

Вбиваем в гугл *"python получить случайный элемент списка"* и находим функцию `choice()` из стандартного модуля `random`.

Выбираем случайного пользователя, исключая самого бота *(он-то тоже поставил реакцию)* и отправляем сообщение, вызывая у выбранного юзера свойство `mention`, чтобы упомянуть:

```
del users[0] # бот первым ставит реакцию, поэтому его индекс - 0
await ctx.send(f'Победитель: {random.choice(users).mention}!')
```

*Почитать про свойства других объектов, по типу `mention` у объекта пользователя можно все в той же [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), это вообще очень полезная штука)*

---

**Полный код:**

```
import discord, asyncio
from random import choice
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def random_pick(ctx, wait_seconds: int):
    msg = await ctx.send('Нажмите  внизу, чтобы участвовать')
    await msg.add_reaction('')

    await asyncio.sleep(wait_seconds)

    msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
    users = await msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    del users[0]
    await ctx.send(f'Победитель: {choice(users).mention}!')


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я и просил информацию. Как раз примерно понял, как искать инфу!

Comment: @I_Uthstar01_I, если ответ решил проблему, могу я попросить вас отметить его как решение? Это даст другим пользователям понять, что вопрос закрыт и можно помочь кому-нибудь еще :)

Comment: Забыл совсем, спасибо ещё раз за алгоритм поиска информации. Буду учить)